# How to run simulation in R to assess sample size and power for SEM?

Tags: r, sample-size, monte-carlo, structural-equation-modeling, statistical-power

Muthén & Muthén offer a MPLUS based syntax for calculating sample size and power on SEM, using a Monte Carlo simulation.

https://www.statmodel.com/download/FinalSEMsingle.pdf

Is there any similar syntax available for R?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't say which package in R you want to use.

You have two choices.

First, calculate your population covariance matrix, and then generate data using the mvrnorm() function in the MASS package. Then estimate your models using your favorite SEM package within R (sem, Lavaan, openMX, etc).

Second,  Lavaan, which has a function called simulateData(). This lets you specify a model to generate in Lavaan language, which you can then estimate.

Comment: Thanks for response, I am looking for a lavaan compatible approach! :)

Comment: simulateData() it is then.